# SQLMetal: How to find Connection String?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I am trying to create a simple offline application for personal-use that uses a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database and I plan to use Linq-to-SQL to work with it. I have used SQLMetal (through the application SqlmetalBuilder) to create a dbml file, and have added it to my project.

The problem I am having is that, unlike the O/P Designer (which you cannot use on SQL Server Compact files), SQLMetal creates code that requires me to enter the connection string when instantiating a DataContext.

How do I find out what the connection string is? I have looked but I can't find the answer... And if there is a way to create the code so that I don't have to enter the connection string (this app is not to be distributed), any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/? http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SqlMetal.exe (Code Generation Tool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx)

See Connection Options:
**/conn:** *connection string*.

**Update:**

[SQL Server Compact 3.5 and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341.aspx) (look for connection string).

You can pass the connection string to [the constructor of DataContext class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721.aspx).